# c - Declaring a variable with both register and static storage classes

Tags: c, gcc, static, c89, register-allocation

(ANSI-C 89)
Hi, is it possible to declare a variable both **static** and **register** ? When ever I try to do this I just get as an error massage: `multiple storage classes in declaration specifiers`

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f1(static int i);
int main()
{
    static register int i;

    i = 5;
    f1(i);
}

void f1(static int i)
{
    static int y =6;
    y+=1;
    printf("\n Y=%d \n",y);
}
```

and th

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to that, because `static` variables are stored in the .bss region, but `register` is stored in a high speed CPU register.

Comment: @stackptr: I don't think that follows from the C standard.

Comment: What do you mean @KerrekSB? Just because the C standard doesn't say anything about where static variables are stored, doesn't mean that most compilers won't allocate static variables in the .bss region.

Comment: @stackptr: Sure, but that has precisely nothing to do with this question. "What most compilers do" is not the justification for why the OP is not allowed to do what she's trying to do.

Comment: It is justification because even if static variables are not stored in bss, they are still stored in memory. which conflicts with `register`, which stores it in the CPU registers. Hence the error. @KerrekSB

Comment: registers must be freed one time or an other, to process other operations. how it can be static if so. also declaring variabale as register do not guaranty that it will be allocated in cpu registers.

Comment: The `register` keyword would be very useful if it entitled a compiler to assume that it could be cached in a register at the compiler's leisure except across operations where the variable's address is taken (so given `register int x; ... foo(&x); ...` a compiler would be required to flush `x` to memory before calling `foo`, but could assume no indirect accesses to `x` would occur after `foo` returned unless its address was taken again.  That would allow useful optimizations which would be simple to implement but are otherwise unachievable.

Comment: @EdwardKarak But in this case it get stored in the .data segment (because the static variable is initialized with a non-zero value).

Answer (score 9):

Both `register` and `static` are storage class specifiers, and at most one storage class specifier can be specified.

From the C11 Standard ISO/IEC 9899:2011:

> **6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers**
>
> **Syntax**
>
> 1. *storage-class-specifier:*
>                `typedef`
>                `extern`
>                `static`
>                `_Thread_local`
>                `auto`
>                `register`
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 2. At most, one storage-class specifier may be given in the declaration specifiers in a declaration, except that `_Thread_local` may appear with `static` or `extern`.<sup>120)</sup>
>
> ---
>
> <sup>120)</sup><sub>See ‘‘future language directions’’ (6.11.5).</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Every object in C has a *storage duration*, which is precisely one of the following: automatic, static, allocated, and (as of C11) thread-local.

With the exception of allocated storage, the storage duration of an object is determined by the linkage of the declared name that refers to the object. (Objects with allocated storage do not have *any* names associated with them.) Linkage of an identifier is determined by the *storage-class specifier* that is present in the declaration. Since an object can only have one type of linkage and one storage duration, the C language only allows you to specify one storage-class specifier (with an exception in C11 for `_Thread_local`).

The linkages and resulting storage durations are as follows:

- `static`: internal linkage, static storage duration
- `extern`: external linkage, static storage duration
- `auto`, `register`: no linkage, automatic storage duration. Only allowed at block scope.
- none: At block scope same as `auto`, at file scope same as `extern`.

As you can see, almost any two storage-class specifiers result in different, incompatible semantics. Therefore, the language simply forbids using more than one storage-class specifier, since for most combinations there it would not be clear which behaviour was requested. It seems that `auto` and `register` are the only two specifiers that could conceivably be applied together. C11 actually adds the exception that `_Thread_local` may appear together with either `extern` or `static`, resulting in the linkage of the latter and thread-local storage duration.

Different storage durations and linkages may require different implementations. Since variables with no linkage need to be unique per scope, they would usually be placed on the function call stack (if they need to be stored). By contrast, a variable with static storage duration needs to persist for the duration of the entire program and thus cannot be placed on a call stack, but instead needs to go in some other part of memory that's available throughout.

Answer (score -2):

You wouldn't be able to that, because static variables are stored in the `.bss` memory region, but register is stored in a high speed CPU register.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss

Comment: Why so many downvotes? This is the best answer from all of them.

Comment: The question is about standard C (C89 to be precise). No C standard specifies the existence of a `.bss` memory region; it defines the behavior of the compiler in terms of storage durations, as the two upvoted descriptions explain. This answer is unhelpful because it speaks to one particular implementation rather than what the language standard requires.

Comment: trentcl has it right. This is the abhorrent "All the world's an Intel" argument.

Comment: `.bss`, even it do not exist in the C-Standard, almost every implementation have a `.bss` section. But a `register`-variable must nor be stored in a physical register.